# Surface area of paraboloide inside sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

Find the surface area of the part of the paraboloide $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$

Setting $2z = x^2+y^2$ I obtain that the points of intersection between the paraboloide and the sphere are $2z+z^2=3$ and thus $z=1$ is the point of intersection, since $z=-3$ is not a solution.

Now in the solution, they parametrize the surface $S$ to $$\vec r(r, \theta) = [rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta), \frac{1}{2}r^2]$$

Since $z=1$ from $2z=r^2$ we obtain that $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$

$$ dS = |\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \theta}| = r\sqrt{r^2+1} drd\theta$$ and thus the surface area is given by

$$ S = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} dS drd\theta$$

My main problem here is understanding the parametrization $$\vec r(r, \theta) = [rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta), \frac{1}{2}r^2]$$How does this parametrize the surface we're interested in? I can understand the components, as we're looking for the surface area of the paraboloide INSIDE the sphere. But the parabloide has a "roof", it gets "cut" by the sphere at $z=1$. How does the limit $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$ account for that? It seems to me they're just integrating some integrand over a circle (the projection of the curve of intersection) without accounting for the "height" here. Can someone shed some light on this for me, please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parametrization $\vec r(r, \theta) = [r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), \frac{1}{2}r^2]$ works since

- $x=r\cos(\theta)$
- $y=r\sin(\theta)$
- $z= \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}r^2$

is such that for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $r\in[0,\sqrt 2]$ we can represent each point $(x,y,\frac{x^2+y^2}{2})$ of the paraboloid cuted by the sphere.

Note that the limit for $r_{max}=\sqrt 2$ comes from the condition that for $z=1$ we have

$$z= \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}=1\implies r^2=x^2+y^2=2 \implies r=\sqrt 2$$